# Error getting trigrams using gensim's Phrases

Tags: python, nlp, data-mining, text-mining, gensim

I want to extract all bigrams and trigrams of the given sentences.

```
from gensim.models import Phrases
documents = ["the mayor of new york was there", "Human Computer Interaction is a great and new subject", "machine learning can be useful sometimes","new york mayor was present", "I love machine learning because it is a new subject area", "human computer interaction helps people to get user friendly applications"]

sentence_stream = [doc.split(" ") for doc in documents]
bigram = Phrases(sentence_stream, min_count=1, threshold=2, delimiter=b' ')
trigram = Phrases(bigram(sentence_stream, min_count=1, threshold=2, delimiter=b' '))

for sent in sentence_stream:
    #print(sent)
    bigrams_ = bigram[sent]
    trigrams_ = trigram[bigrams_]

    print(bigrams_)
    print(trigrams_)
```

The code works fine for bigrams and capture 'new york' and 'machine learning' ad bigrams.

However, I get the following error when I try to insert trigrams.

```
TypeError: 'Phrases' object is not callable
```

Please let me know, how to correct my code.

I am following the [example documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) of gensim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html), you can do:

```
from gensim.models import Phrases
from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser 

phrases = Phrases(sentence_stream)
bigram = Phraser(phrases)
trigram = Phrases(bigram[sentence_stream])
```

`bigram`, being a `Phrases` object, cannot be called again, as you are doing so.

Comment: Then I get the error saying: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable :(

Comment: @Volka I took a look at the docs, and found something that I think would work.

Comment: Thanks it works. However, my model is still not capturing trigrams (e.g., human computer interaction). Maybe, I will ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @Volka No need to... the docs I linked to has all the information you need. I think you need to use the `Phraser` class documented there.

Comment: @Volka Furthermore, I think `bigram = Phrases(sentence_stream)` is enough... I suspect the other params might be causing trouble.

Comment: Itried to use Phraser as well as follows `bigram = Phrases(sentence_stream, min_count=1, threshold=2, delimiter=b' ')
bigram_phraser = Phraser(bigram)`. However, it didn't work :(

Comment: @Volka Interesting... I tried running the code in the docs and it doesn't work for me. Maybe you should open a new question after all...

Comment: this example code is all wrong, whence are you importing Phrases? Also variable p is undefined